# Database for Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

First of all, I am learning myself Django through online tutorial. I am stuck with settings.py not knowing what should be the databases should I set.I  dont think my pc has any database or its driver inbuilt. So how can I proceed?

Secondly, when I run Manage.py runserver, I dont get it run anything on my CMD. Is it because I didnt set up my db on settings file?

Thirdly, I am completely new to IT and programming language as I have a Biological science background.I somewhat learnt Python, BeautifulSoup, Pandas etc., Will I able to learn Django? Do I need any prerequistes or do I also need to learn javascript, CSS etc.,

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: If you create a django project by `django-admin` don't need to setup database manually. In django project default database setup is `sqlite3`. For learning purpose, this is enough. For this, you don't need any driver.

Answer (score 0):

1. For learning and dev purposes, use sqlite database. Use this in your settings file:

   `DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
           'NAME': 'mydatabase',
       }
   }`
2. You should get an error or a message that the dev server has been started and it is listening on localhost:8000

   Make sure you have installed python and django correctly. I recommend you to follow this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/windows/
3. Yes you are good to learn django! Also learn HTML CSS along the way. All the best.

Comment: not seems to be working still. Please note, I have python3 in C drive and Django Project @ D Drive. Will it be a problem?

Comment: If you open cmd and type in `python --version` does it work?

Comment: Yes it shows Python 3.6.5. When I run it from here C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32

Comment: So try `python manage.py runserver` from your django project directory and check the output.